# Android Studio not recognizing uses-permission in the AndroidManifest

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-manifest

I am having problem where it seems my Android Studio is not recognizing the uses-permission in my AndroidManifest.xml file. In my main activity, when I try to call for some function that requires INTERNET and ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, the activity seems to not recognize that I have already put the permission in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

The following is the method that calls for the ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE. The part when calling

```
public boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
        boolean isOnline = false;
        ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        try {
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                NetworkCapabilities capabilities = manager.getNetworkCapabilities(manager.getActiveNetwork());
                isOnline = capabilities != null && capabilities.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED);
            } else {
                NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                isOnline = activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return isOnline;
    }

private void showConnectDialog() {
        Log.d(TAG, "showConnectDialog: trying to show the connect dialog");
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this,R.style.MyAlertDialogStyle);
        builder.setMessage("Please connect to the internet to proceed further")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Connect", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));
                    }
                });
        builder.show();
    }
```

In my main activity oncreate:

```
if (!isNetworkAvailable(MainActivity.this)){
            showConnectDialog();
        }
        if (isServicesOK()) {
            init();
        }

MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
            }
        });
        AdView mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adViewMain);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

You can see in the images (attached below) show that I have an error in my isNetworkAvailable method, and also my Google AdMob. If I hover my mouse on the error, Android Studio mentioned that I need to add ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE permission for the isNetworkAvailable method, and INTERNET permission for the Google AdMob. But I already have them in my AndroidManifest.xml. **Am I missing anything else?** Thank you very much for your help.

[Error in Google AdMob](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsPaE.png)

[Error in isNetworkAvailable method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cyu9k.png)

Comment: what happens when you run the code?

Comment: Also what is the android version? also note for some permission eg the ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION you actually need runtime permission request as of LOLLIPOP_MR1m. have you tried invalidating cache and or restarting android studio if the code runs ?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It actually runs completely fine, but I just don't know why it shows the error. I copied these methods from my other project (that already works fine with these codes in the past), but I don't know why when I reuse them in this new project, Android Studio is showing error (even though they work).

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you fix it?

Comment: For me the issue is windows firewall/defender or antivirus blocked android studio from accessing the internet. Whitelist android studio then clean the project.

Comment: add your `Menifest` code in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Something might be wrong in your AndroidManifest.xml file. When you open the AndroidManifest.xml, click on the "Merged Manifest" button. It may show you if you have a problem in it.

Comment: The problem was fixed after a specifing a "package" tag in subproject's `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: You have saved my day man. In my case, i don't know why my `<meta-data>` did not recognize `MAPS_API_KEY` placeholder value. At least, now I know where to look next. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code on my own and it runs successfully. ;)

```
package com.mansi.stackissue;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkCapabilities;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (!isNetworkAvailable(MainActivity.this)){
            showConnectDialog();
        }


        MobileAds.initialize(this, initializationStatus -> {
        });
        AdView mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adViewMain);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

    public boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
        boolean isOnline = false;
        ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        try {
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                NetworkCapabilities capabilities = manager.getNetworkCapabilities(manager.getActiveNetwork());
                isOnline = capabilities != null && capabilities.hasCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_VALIDATED);
            } else {
                NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                isOnline = activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return isOnline;
    }

    private void showConnectDialog() {
        Log.d("TAG", "showConnectDialog: trying to show the connect dialog");
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this,R.style.Theme_AppCompat_DayNight_Dialog_Alert);
        builder.setMessage("Please connect to the internet to proceed further")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Connect", (dialog, i) -> startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS)));
        builder.show();
    }
}
```

Manifest File (Add your APP ID)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mansi.stackissue">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.StackIssue">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-**********"/>
</application>
```

Layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adViewMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="YOUR_UNIT_ID" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Please clean your project and re-build again. It will works.
Happy Coding!!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It works completely fine on my Android Studio as well, but I just don't know why it shows the error. I copied these methods from my other project (that already works fine with these codes in the past), but I don't know why when I reuse them in this new project, Android Studio is showing error.